# Conditional ternary Javascript not picking up api call

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am making an api call where a property may or may not exist.  My first thought was wrapping that in a ternary statement would fix this issue, however, it is not.

```
 newObject.fax_from      = value.from.phoneNumber  === 'undefined' ? 'none' :  value.from.phoneNumber;
```

When the property this not exist in the api return data, I get a message that

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'phoneNumber' of undefined
```

any ideas?

I even tried to be more specific such as

```
 newObject.fax_from      = value.from.phoneNumber = typeof( value.from.phoneNumber) == 'undefined' ? 'none' :  value.from.phoneNumber;
```

Comment: The error says `from` is undefined. Use `value.from?.phoneNumber`. Also, you are adding quotes around `undefined`. It should  either be `a === undefined` <-- without quotes or `typeof a === 'undefined'` <-- because typeof returns a string

Comment: `value.from.phoneNumber  === 'undefined'` looks to see if it has the value `"undefined"` (a string). `undefined` is just `undefined` (no quotes). Also, it would appear that `value.from` (not `value.from.phoneNumber`) is what's `undefined`. In modern environments you can use optional chaining and nullish coalescing: `newObject.fax_from = value.from?.phoneNumber ?? "none";` In older environments, probably `newObject.fax_from = (value.from && value.from.phoneNumber) ? value.from.phoneNumber : "none";` if you also want to use `"none"` when `value.from.phoneNumber` is a blank string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yea, I tried undefined with no quotes as well, and the same result.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this actually worked `value.from?.phoneNumber ?? "none";` that was odd, any reason as to how that is working?

Comment: @chewie - See [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).